# Win7 HomeGroup Sharing works fine with files under my User dir, but not with files under D:\

Tags: windows-7, windows, home-networking, file-sharing, homegroup

I have successfully shared (and accessed from another pc) files and dirs under `C:\Users\Stefan`. But when I try to share a dir under `D:\`, I get a window saying "Your folder can't be shared". Why does this happen? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen?

In Microsoft culture, sharing a whole volume is taboo. Don't ask me why.

> Is there a workaround?

Lots of!

1. Move all your files into a subfolder and share the subfolder instead.
2. Share your drive using Advanced Sharing. Right-click on the volume, select, Properties, go to "Sharing" tab and you will know where to go from there.
3. Share your drive using Computer Management snap-in. To start it, right-click on Computer icon and select "Manage". In the left tree, Computer Management, System Tools, Shared Folders, Shares. Then right click in the right pane and select "New Share...". You'll know what to do afterwards.
4. Share your drive using NET SHARE command. Here is the help dump:

```
The syntax of this command is:

NET SHARE
sharename
          sharename=drive:path [/GRANT:user,[READ | CHANGE | FULL]]
                               [/USERS:number | /UNLIMITED]
                               [/REMARK:"text"]
                               [/CACHE:Manual | Documents| Programs | BranchCache | None]
          sharename [/USERS:number | /UNLIMITED]
                    [/REMARK:"text"]
                    [/CACHE:Manual | Documents | Programs | BranchCache | None]
          {sharename | devicename | drive:path} /DELETE
          sharename \\computername /DELETE
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to share the entire `D:/`, just a dir under `D:/`, e.g. `D:/foo`. I thought that was understandable from my question :) Will your points 2, 3 and 4 be applicable in that case?